# Regex: How to parse comma seperated string, recurring group?

Tags: python, regex

I want to parse a string via RegEx (in real world my example is much more complex, else I would use `split`)

This:

```
import re 
regex="([a-z])(?:,([a-z]))*$" 
p=re.compile(regex)
print(p.findall("a,b,c,d,e"))
```

Outputs:

> [('a', 'e')]

But I would expect:

> ['a','b','c','d','e']

As I did group up the [a-z] sequences.

How can I get this desired behaviour?

Comment: Well, this is so common a question. See the linked question answers. Pay attention to the answer using PyPi `regex` that has the feature support that you need.